# Wireless Mac Keyboard Acts Sporadic, PI3

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I have a Pi 3, Mac keyboard and magic trackpad.

I have both of the devices attached to my Pi 3 using the built-in Bluetooth and they both respond, but when I type it misses keys and can get stuck typing one key.

I am testing this with my Pi out of its case and ~ 3 inches from the keyboard.

I don't think it's a range issue as my track pad works with it from ~ 2-3m.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the keyboard work with other devices as expected?

Comment: @DarthVader Yes, it works correctly with any other device I use it on.

Comment: Okay so its a problem at the Pi end, it might be there is not enough bandwidth for 2 Bluetooth devices. Could you try with just the keyboard connected?

Comment: That's it! It seems the trackpad hogs all the bandwidth, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem at the Pi end, it might be there is not enough bandwidth for 2 Bluetooth devices. I expect the keyboard will work with the trackpad disconnected.